# Str split with expand in Dask Dataframe

Tags: python, string, split, bigdata, dask

I have 34 million row and only have a column. I want to split string into 4 column.

Here is my sample dataset (df):

```
    Log
0   Apr  4 20:30:33 100.51.100.254 dns,packet user: --- got query from 10.5.14.243:30648:
1   Apr  4 20:30:33 100.51.100.254 dns,packet user: id:78a4 rd:1 tc:0 aa:0 qr:0 ra:0 QUERY 'no error'
2   Apr  4 20:30:33 100.51.100.254 dns,packet user: question: tracking.intl.miui.com:A:IN
3   Apr  4 20:30:33 dns user: query from 9.5.10.243: #4746190 tracking.intl.miui.com. A
```

I want to split it into four column using this code:

```
df1 = df['Log'].str.split(n=3, expand=True)
df1.columns=['Month','Date','Time','Log']
df1.head()
```

Here is the result that i expected

```
     Month Date      Time                                              Log
0      Apr    4  20:30:33  100.51.100.254 dns,packet user: --- go...
1      Apr    4  20:30:33  100.51.100.254 dns,packet user: id:78a...
2      Apr    4  20:30:33  100.51.100.254 dns,packet user: questi...
3      Apr    4  20:30:33  dns transjakarta: query from 9.5.10.243: #474...
4      Apr    4  20:30:33  100.51.100.254 dns,packet user: --- se...
```

but the respond is like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-c9b2023fbf3e> in <module>
----> 1 df1 = df['Log'].str.split(n=3, expand=True)
      2 df1.columns=['Month','Date','Time','Log']
      3 df1.head()

TypeError: split() got an unexpected keyword argument 'expand'
```

Is there any solution to split the string using dask?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Edit: this works now

Dask dataframe does support the str.split method's expand= keyword *if* you provide an `n=` keyword as well to tell it how many splits to expect.

### Old answer

It looks like dask dataframes's `str.split` method doesn't implement the expand= keyword.  You might raise an issue if one does not already exist.

As a short term workaround, you could make a Pandas function, and then use the [map_partitions](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.Series.map_partitions) method to scale that across your dask dataframe

```
def f(df: pandas.DataFrame) -> pandas.DataFrame:
    """ This is your code from above, as a function """
    df1 = df['Log'].str.split(n=3, expand=True)
    df1.columns=['Month','Date','Time','Log']
    return df

ddf = ddf.map_partitions(f)  # apply to all pandas dataframes within dask dataframe
```

Because Dask dataframes are just collections of Pandas dataframes it's relatively easy to build things yourself when Dask dataframe doesn't support them.

Answer (score 0):

For those like me that did not find `str.split` with the `expand=True` argument to work even when using the `n=` parameter, I wanted to point out that the ["Old answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55881730/4420657) from @MRocklin is incomplete (at least was for me):
it is missing a join of the new DF with the original:

```
def f(df: pandas.DataFrame) -> pandas.DataFrame:
    df1 = df['Log'].str.split(n=3, expand=True)
    df1.columns=['Month','Date','Time','Log']
    *df = df.join(df1)*
    return df
```

Now, for me, there was another *gotcha*:

```
ValueError: The columns in the computed data do not match the columns in the provided metadata
  Extra:   ['1', '2', '3', '4']
  Missing: []
```

To rectify, add:

```
for col in [f'{num}' for num in range(4)]:
    df1[col] = df1.get(col, float('nan'))
```

And here's the whole shebang:

```
data = {
    'Log': ['a;1;2;3', 'b;1;', 'c', 'd;1;2'],
    'dummy_col': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
}
df = dd.from_dict(data, npartitions=2)  # I made sure to choose a partition count lower than my row number.

def f(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    tmp_df = df['Log'].str.split(';', expand=True)  # New DF of just the splits. Looks something like this:
        # (but remember, Dask is passing _partitions_ to `f`, not the whole DF)
        #
        #       0   1   2   3
        #   0   a   1   2   3
        #   1   b   1       <NA>
    df = df.drop(columns=['Log'])
    new_col_names = ['Month','Date','Time','Log']
    tmp_df.columns = new_col_names[:len(tmp_df.columns)]  # Slice to only the columns within the current _partition_. Because only partitions are passed to `f`, we need to accommodate an odd partition that may have _no_ rows and therefore also have _no_ columns. TODO Someone please knowledge-check me on this.
    for col in new_col_names:
        tmp_df[col] = tmp_df.get(col, float('nan'))  # Fill in with blank if this partition happens not to have all the newly split columns
    df = df.join(tmp_df)  # add the newly split columns to the existing columns.
    return df

df = df.map_partitions(f)
df.compute()
```

Thank you so much @MRocklin for your answer to this question (and the *many* other answers you have throughout SO). Could not have solved my problem without your help.